# get positions to be saved in delivery via ABAP

Tags: abap

I am trying to check if positions in a delivery which is changed via the transaction **vl02n** fulfill some specific critiria before the document is saved.

For this action I want to use the user exit **USEREXIT_SAVE_DOCUMENT_PREPARE**.

In the debugger I checked which tables and variables are accessible and found out that there is a global table **XLIPS** which contains all positions that are visible on the current to be saved delivery.

The problem is that in XLIPS there are also the positions which were already deleted at the GUI of vl02n. 
Because I just want to check the positions which indeed will be saved I don't want to use the table XLIPS.

How could I solve this problem and is there a better way than using XLIPS?

Thank you very much for your help and please excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XLIPS` contains the change information of all delivery items upon saving. So if you delete a line, `XLIPS` will still hold the deleted line, with the field `XLIPS-UPDKZ` set to `D` - indicating that the line has been deleted (or `I` inserted or `U` updated). With this in mind, you should be able to program your checks against the relevant items accordingly:

```
LOOP AT xlips ... WHERE updkz NE 'D'.
    <your code here>
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me out.